# Public key Exceeding Mod P? A Clarification Request On The Discrete Logarithm Problem

Tags: public-key, cryptography, encryption, secp256k1

I tried to observe / implement the discrete logarithm problem but I noticed something about it; but before I get into it let me give some clarification which is open to correction.

> > a = b^x mod P
>
> Where as
>
> a = the public key of the address;
>
> b = the generator point of the secp256k1 koblitz curve (this is the
> curve in context);
>
> x = the discrete log;
>
> P = the modular integer.

I coupled all parameters below:

> A =
> 044f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa385b6b1b8ead809ca67454d9683fcf2ba03456d6fe2c4abe2b07f0fbdbb2f1c1
> (uncompressed public key)
> 034f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa :
> (compressed public key)
>
> B = 04 79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07 029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B
> 16F81798 483ADA77 26A3C465 5DA4FBFC 0E1108A8 FD17B448 A6855419
> 9C47D08F FB10D4B8 (uncompressed generator point)
>
> 02 79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07 029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B
> 16F81798 (compress generator point)
>
> X = ?
>
> P = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE
> FFFFFC2F

I don't actually know what part of the parameters I should use ( compressed or uncompressed)

N. B :  I tried the uncompressed public key to Mod P but the uncompressed public key exceeded the Mod P in size.

What should I do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to note that the Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem (ECDLP) is slightly different from the normal Discrete Logarithm Problem (DLP).

In DLP, the `^` operator is actually exponentiation and it is operating on integers so `mod p` is just the normal modulus. However for ECDLP, `^` is actually elliptic curve point multiplication. This is different from exponentiation and is a much more involved process. You also cannot `mod p` with a point because they are not integers. While there is a modulo, it is part of the point multiplication process itself.

The compressedness of the parameters you use does not really matter. In the end, the compression is just the encoding of a point. You need to parse this encoding to determine the X and Y coordinates of the point; both uncompressed and compressed allow you to determine them. The uncompressed just gives you the X and Y coordinates directly while the compressed one gives you the X and whether Y is even or odd so that you can compute the correct Y coordinate. When you do the point multiplication, you are not handling the encoded point as an integer and just multiplying it with `x`. You are doing elliptic curve point multiplication which is way more complicated.

Comment: But when i tried to use the uncompressed public key to solve for the Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem; mod p was actually smaller than the public key. what shoud i do about that?

Comment: @DaveKent How are you trying to solve for ECDLP?

Comment: I actually converted the uncompressed public key from hexadecimal to decimal, same as the prime mod P. And as for how I'm going to solve it... It's still in theory;passed some tests though.... So yeah I'm good.